# What module better to use in game developing on appcelerator?

Tags: appcelerator

Advice me some actual module for appcelerator to use 2D and 3D graphics!
I will be glad for free download links!

Answer (score 1):

Best one is Platino. Not free but not terribly expensive either. Get it here http://www.blackgategames.com